# Flot line graphs in popups have overlapping axis labels

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, popup, flot

I have a table of data with some hover-activated popups. These popups are simply `div` elements with `position: absolute` and `display: none` initially set; a few lines of JavaScript then hide or show them based on mouse hovering. A flot line graph is attached to each popup.

This works great and fast, except for one hitch. Flot has a bug which causes the x-axis and y-axis labels to overlap at the lower-left corner when the graph is part of a popup like this. In short, the solution is to display the containing div before generating the graph.

I tried a solution in which I eliminated the initial `display: none` from the CSS for each popup div. I also eliminated the `background-color` and `border` style elements, effectively making these divs invisible. Then some simple jQuery generates the graphs and does the proper CSS styling for these popups (setting the background-color, border, etc.). This works, functionally. The graph labels are now correctly positioned. But it's *slow*. It easily triples the loading time of the page, which is unacceptable.

Simply adding `display: none` back into the initial CSS for the popup divs solves all the performance problems. So the jQuery code itself cannot be the bottleneck. But that of course causes the label formatting to be messed up again.

Does anybody know how to overcome this issue?

Comment: You are going to have to show some code or some pictures or a fiddle or something...

Comment: It's really not all that simple to reproduce all the moving pieces for this in a fiddle. I think for someone who actually knows the solution to this problem my description is sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem by just deferring the generation of each graph until the initial corresponding mouse hover event is fired. I also had to initially set the z-index of the containing divs to be -1 and then change this to 1 upon generation of the graph; otherwise the invisible div would "cover up" other page content, making it impossible to, say, click on links "behind" the div before the graph was generated.

Answer (score 1):

As you discovered, Flot must draw into a div that's attached to the DOM.  I can't say for sure without an example, but I would guess that your slow performance is probably due to the fact that the divs, even if they have no content, are still on-screen, and so you're triggering a redraw whenever you change them.

Instead of hiding the background and border, simply absolute-position the div far off-screen, e.g. `top:-9999px; left:-9999px`.  That way it's still in layout, so Flot can make its measurements, but the browser is smart enough not to redraw something off-screen.

Comment: Thanks very much for your response. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be improving the performance. Is it possible that the positioning measurements done by flot are directly responsible for the slowdown? The page freezes presumably while flot is generating the graphs; there are about 85 line graphs in total being generated on the page.

Comment: Possibly; can't really say without seeing it.  If it is, then you might also try drawing the plots one at a time instead of all at one, using setTimeout(<draw helper>, 0) to give some time back to the browser.